# How to shape return data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

While returning data in Postman, I receive full user information such as password hash and password salt. My idea is to return only his username, so that it looks like "user" : "tom" without his data. I should use automapper ? Or how to set the Dto's to return correct data. Any tips ?

```
public async Task < ActionResult < ProductDto[] >> AddProduct(string username,
ProductDto productDto) 
{
    User u = await _context.Users
                           .Where(x => x.UserName == username)
                           .Include(x => x.Products)
                           .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (u != null) 
    {
        var product = new Product 
                          {
                              Name = productDto.Name,
                              Price = productDto.Price,
                              UserId = u.Id
                          };
        u.Products.Add(product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return u.Products.ToArray();
}

public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set ;}
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Output in postman: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNi7J.png

Comment: What does the `User` class look like?

Comment: *... so that it looks like "user" : "tom"*. I don't see you creating this look anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an array of `Product` objects, but it seems that what you really want is to return an array of `ProductDto` objects.

You can use the following code to construct the array of `ProductDto` objects. Insert it after the `if (u != null)` check:

```
if (u != null)
{
    var product = new Product 
    {
        Name = productDto.Name,
        Price = productDto.Price,
        UserId = u.Id
    };
    u.Products.Add(product);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
else
{
    return new ProductDto[] {};
}

var productDtos = new ProductDto[u.Products.Count];
for (var i = 0; i < u.Products.Count; i++)
{
    productDtos[i] = new ProductDto
    {
        Name = product.Name,
        Username = product.User.UserName,
        Price = product.Price
    };
}

return productDtos;
```

Alternatively, you can use LINQ:

```
if (u != null)
{
    var product = new Product 
    {
        Name = productDto.Name,
        Price = productDto.Price,
        UserId = u.Id
    };
    u.Products.Add(product);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
else
{
    return new ProductDto[] {};
}

var productDtos = u.Products
    .Select(p => new ProductDto
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        Username = p.User.UserName,
        Price = p.Price
    })
    .ToArray();

return productDtos;
```

Comment: If there are more columns, you can automate that with `ProjectTo`.

Comment: Your code looks fine, but you are missing adding created product to user's list.

Comment: And one more question in your first option what product is?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Right, that requires AutoMapper though, doesn't it?

Comment: @szymix1322 Updated my answer for clarity.